# How can I test whether integers from one list are divisible by integers from another?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to create a function that takes an `Int` (`n`), and a list `k` of `Int`s, and returns the sum of all numbers `1 <= i <= n`, that are divisible by at least one of the integers from list `k`.

```
addl::Int -> [Int] -> Int
addl x [] = 0
addl x (y:ys) = if  ((map [1..x] `mod` y) == 0) 
                  then y + addl x ys 
                  else 0 + addl x ys
```

This is what I got, but I get this message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> b0' with actual type `[t0]'
    In the first argument of `map', namely `[1 .. x]'
    In the first argument of `mod', namely `map [1 .. x]'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `(map [1 .. x] `mod` y)'
```

which I've tried to figure out, but just haven't understood yet.
All help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with map? map takes a function and a list, so you got the signature wrong.

Comment: Trying to make sure that it mods every number in [1..x] with y

Comment: Did you mean `add1 n k = sum $ filter (\x -> any ((==0) . mod x) k) [1..n]` ?

Comment: watch out for the order of predicates. It seems what you are summing up are the _y_ s from the list _k_, not _i_ s that are divisible by some _y_.

Comment: The title should be an English sentence. Do *not* add tags there as in "blah blah blah? Haskell" or "X, Y: some question?"; there's already the tag field for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` expects a function as its first argument, but you supply it with a list.

Error message is saying as much. It indicates that the expression `` ((map [1..x] `mod` y) == 0) `` is parsed as

```
(==)   -- In the first argument of `(==)', namely `(map [1 .. x] `mod` y)'
    mod     -- In the first argument of `mod', namely `map [1 .. x]'
        map [1..x]  -- In the first argument of `map', namely `[1 .. x]'
        y
    0
         -- Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> b0' with actual type `[t0]'
```

`map`'s type is

```
Prelude> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]

Prelude> :t [undefined]
[undefined] :: [a]
```

and `(a1 -> b1)` and `[a2]` do not match.

Instead of mixing the two actions (the filtering and the summation) in your code, confusingly (you even sum the wrong variable `y` there),  it's simpler to modularize the process to first searching, and only then, summing:

```
addl::Int -> [Int] -> Int
addl n ks = sum                                         -- then, sum
                [i | i <- [1..n], isDividedByAny i ks]   -- first, search
  where
     isDividedByAny i ks = 
         any   
            [ rem i k == 0 | k <- ks]
```

Here we use the built-in function `any` of type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` (i.e. it gets a predicate function, a list of values, and returns a Boolean value).

Note how I call your `k` list `ks` here, to suggest it's a list of "k"'s. This is idiomatic in Haskell.